# Validar datos en react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una funcion con la cual quiero validar si los datos que se estan pasando como parametros estan vacios; si estan vacios se convierte en 0 en caso contrario pasa el valor que se le envia.

```
validar(){
    this.setState({nombre:"", apellido:"", email:""});

    if( this.state.tipo_contacto == 1){
        this.state.id = "/0";
        this.state.value = "/"+ 1;
        if(document.getElementById('nombre').value != ""){
            this.state.nombre = "/"+ ascii_to_hexa(document.getElementById('nombre').value);
        }else{
            this.state.nombre = "/0";
        }
        if(document.getElementById('apellido').value != ""){
            this.state.apellido = "/"+ ascii_to_hexa(document.getElementById('apellido').value);
        }else{
            this.state.apellido = "/0";
        }
        if(document.getElementById('email').value != ""){
            this.state.email = "/"+ ascii_to_hexa(document.getElementById('email').value);
         }else{
            this.state.email = "/0";
         }    
    }
 }

 getSearchPerson(){
    this.validar();
    CleverRequest.get(CleverConfig.getApiUrl('profile')+'/clientes/filtroparametroscontac/' +  this.props.value + '/' + this.state.id +  '/' + this.state.name + '/' + this.state.apellido + '/' + this.state.email + '/' + this.state.limit + '/' + this.state.offset,(response,error) => 
    {
        if(!error)
        {
            this.setState({
                getSearchEmpresa : response,
            })
        }else
        {
            console.log(error);
        };
    });
}
```

Ese es mi codigo pero no funciona y no se que estoy haciendo mal.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Cuando dices que tu código no funciona, ¿qué ocurre? ¿está arrojando algún error? o crees que hay fallos en la lógica de implementación? Revisando tu código puedo ver que estás asignándole un valor al state directamente y no por medio de `.setState` cosa que [tag:reactjs] recomienda que no hagas y otra cosa que veo es la forma en la que llamas el atributo `value` de cada input cuando podrías hacerlo todo con react y hacer tu código más escalable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haré una respuesta sin saber bien el problema que tienes, pero al ayudarte a refactorizar el código y a entender un poco más el funcionamiento de [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) entonces podrás solucionar más rápido, y seguro te ayude a aclarar mucho.

Lo primero que veo, es la forma en la que usas tus inputs, y cuando te menciono que puedes hacer el código más escalable, es porque puedes bindear una función a tus inputs para luego no tener que buscarlos en el DOM (Esto es algo importante de las tecnologías reactivas y la velocidad del DOM), para ello puedes hacer esto:

```
<!-- defines tu input en html normal !-->
<input name="nombre" onChange={this.onChangeInput.bind(this)} />
```

Le hacemos *bind* al método `onChange` para que cada que cambie llame a una función que vas a definir en tu componente, como le pusimos `onChangeInput` entonces la llamamos igual:

```
// En algún lado de tu componente, donde defines tus métodos
onChangeInput(event) {
    // 'event' es el evento nativo, el cual tiene un objetivo (target)
    // que viene siendo el nodo en el DOM (O sea, el input que definimos antes),
    // por lo que podemos llamar al atributo 'name' (que lo definimos),
    // y el atributo 'value' (lo mismo que document.getElementById('nombre').value)
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

Con `[event.target.name] : event.target.value` le decimos a react que guarde en el estado una nueva llave con el nombre del input que cambió, y le setee el valor que el usuario escogió en el input. Fácil :)

Ahora tu método de validación. Lo explicaré en el código:

```
validate() {
  // OJO que comenté esto
  // this.setState({ nombre: '', apellido: '', email: '' });
  // Lo comento porque no sé la razón de tenerlo, además que los inputs tomarán esos valores,
  // y si no lo comento, entonces la validación no servirá, pero si necesitas limpiar
  // estos valores antes de validar, siempre puedes crear unos adicionales, o llamar
  // a tus inputs con un prefijo. Por ejemplo 'input_nombre'

  if (this.state.tipo_contact === 1) {  // usa === en vez de ==
    this.setState({
      id: "/0",
      value: "\1",
      nombre: this.state.nombre.trim() ? `/${ascii_to_hexa(this.state.nombre)}` : '/0',
      apellido: this.state.apellido.trim() ? `/${ascii_to_hexa(this.state.apellido)}` : '/0',
      email: this.state.email.trim() ? `/${ascii_to_hexa(this.state.email)}` : '/0',
    });
  }
}
```

Básicamente cuando valida está asignándole a cada variable un '/0' si está vacío o el valor de acuerdo a la función `ascii_to_hexa` si tiene un valor.

Como te repito, no sé si esto dé con la solución a tu pregunta y respuesta, pero si puede ser gran causa del problema, y puede que el código que puse aquí no te funcione tal cual, más si necesitas tener en variables diferentes el valor del input y por otro lado el valor que asignas con tu función de `ascii_to_hex`, pero básicamente, la corrección que había que hacerle a tu código fuera de la lógica, era la forma como asignabas los valores al estado.

Cualquier pregunta o inquietud que tengas me comentas y con gusto te ayudaré a resolverla